Need to know something about semen in tantras
https://sci-hub.scrongyao.com/10.2307/3176673 this is a research paper on a tantric text which basically says that mixing of semen and menstrual blood was used in initiation rituals in tantra or to please the goddess. Then after a while the writer of the paper points out how abhinavagupta used a complex system of sounds to transform many of the heavily criticized Kaula practices into purely symbolic ones.
Now my question is Q1) How can this tantra mentioned above ask sadhaka to ejaculate his sperm and use it in his puja/ritual when in Shiva samhita Lord Shiva says one should not ejaculate or waste his semen ,also explaining how even a householder can attain liberation by learning vajroli mudra and basically never ejaculating when orgasming so as to not waste his seminal fluid+sperm and he explains how loss of semen is equal to death of a person basically saying its bad and should be avoided. He also explain there that how one can achieve this by holding in the sperm, like trying to tighten our penis muscles to hold in pee, when we are nearing ejaculation. My source for this is this website so if what this website is saying is incorrect do correct me : https://glorian.org/learn/scriptures/hindu/siva-samhita-preserve-the-semen
Q2) My second question is , in tantra there are many layers of symbolism and as far i have heard, practices which involve actually having sex or doing something physical are more for people who are more tamasic, or people who can't do those meditative rituals which don't involve doing anything physical so I wanted to confirm is this true or am i wrong?
*Also just a slight edit here, If anyone has more research papers or articles in english or translations of tantric texts I want to read them and it would be appreciated if you provide me links for those.
